# Count number of controllers of a certain type

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to know how many controllers of a certain type exist (I don't mean `Initialized`, I mean `Exist`)
I'm thinking this should be easy and that I'm missing something.

For example:

```
<body ng-app="waitfor">
     <div ng-controller="oneof">
        {{cindex}} {{last}}
     </div>
     <div ng-controller="oneof">
       {{cindex}} {{last}}
     </div>
      <div ng-controller="oneof">
        {{cindex}} {{last}}
     </div>
</body>
```

I want to know that 3 `oneof` controllers exist so when the last one is initialized I can act accordingly.

Comment: When would you need to repeat the same controller over and over again? You could do this in alot of ways. But it should not be the oneof controller responsibility

Comment: It shouldn't be the controllers responsibility, ofcourse. 
The scenario is that each controller registers with a service and on every registration there needs to be some kind of calculation done. I want to postpone this calculation until all controllers are finished. I think the service can determine when they are done, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Ben: Did you try my solution ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Just noticed the answer. I read it, you actually gave a method to find out how many controllers were instantiated (because you register at instantiation) and I was looking for a method to find how many exist in total (In other words - how many elements have `ng-controller="oneof"` even before instantiation (In the service). 

See the difference?

Comment: @Ben: My method keeps a count of currently "active" instances (e.g. instantiated and not destroyed (as in element removed)). I don't really understand what you want to count. You say elements with `ng-controller="oneof"`. But where should you look for those elements ? In the whole codebase ? I a single HTML file ? What about partials that are loaded (e.g. using `ngView`, `ngInclude`, directive templates) ? What about elements that are removed from the DOM (e.g.  using `ngIf`) ? I think you are walking very thin ice here. Make sure you fully understand how Angular handles its stuff.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Basically, I'm looking for the angular answer to "How many elements are registered to use controller `oneof`". 
For example, The closest `jQuery` way to ask that would have been `$("*[ng-controller='onof']");` (I might have to do this if there is no `angular` way). 
Like I said, I have to know when the last controller of this type has been instantiated.

Comment: @Ben: Angular is not jQuery. In Angular elements are added and removed from the DOM "on the fly" and there is no such thing as "registered to use controller `oneof`". Elements are inserted and compiled by Angular and if there is a controller attached to them (e.g. `ngController`) the controller is instantiated. There is no way to find that out beforehand, because it is not known beforehand (it depends on the user's actions/choices).

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is not the case for you, since you have your elements laid out on the DOM and they are not subject to dynamic change (at least the elements with `oneof` controller. In that case, I don't see a more straight-forward approach than querying the DOM. Yet, if that is indeed the case (all elements on the DOM and no dynamic modification), why do you think that the controllers are not initialized right-away ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Let me explain the problem, get a larger perspective and maybe you might have a solution for the larger problem. Suppose that for every controller I have to run `f(n)` where n is the number of registered controllers so far of the same type. The results for `f(n-1)` are discarded so there is no need to run `f(1)` to `f(n-1)`, only the last `f(n)` (assume f() does computation, not heavy but would rather avoid redundant cpu time). `f(n)` is run in the controller initialization.  

So this is the problem. How would you solve this? (I will rephrase in the question itself)

Comment: Are all the elements going to be present in the original HTML ? Are there elements that get inserted later (e.g. inside `ngInclude`, `ngIf`, directive templates) ?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need:

1. A service that keeps track of the existing controllers and exposes methods for registering/unregistering a controller instance.
2. A controller that uses the service to register itself on instantiation and unregisters itself once destroyed.

---

Sample implementation:

**1.)** The service:

```
.factory('OneOfManyManager', function () {
    /* Internal list of existing controller
     * (i.e. instantated and not destroyed) */
    var ctrls = [];

    /* Returns the current count of existing controllers */
    function getCount() {
        return ctrls.length;
    }

    /* Registers a controller instance and returns its index
     * (NOTE: With this implementation, indices are not necessarily unique) */
    function register(ctrl) {
        var idx = ctrls.length;
        ctrls.push(ctrl);
        return idx;
    }

    /* Unregisters a controller (if already registered)
     * Return true upon successful unregistration of false otherwise */
    function unregister(ctrl) {
        var idx = ctrls.indexOf(ctrl);
        ctrls.splice(idx, 1);
        return idx !== -1;
    }

    /* The returned service object */
    return {
        getCount:   getCount,
        register:   register,
        unregister: unregister
    };
});
```

**2.)** The controller:

```
.controller('oneOfManyCtrl', function ($scope, OneOfManyManager) {
    var thisCtrl = this;

    /* Register the controller upon instantition */
    $scope.index    = OneOfManyManager.register(thisCtrl);
    $scope.getCount = OneOfManyManager.getCount;

    /* Unregister the controller once upon destruction */
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function (evt) {
        var success = OneOfManyManager.unregister(thisCtrl);
        if (success) {
            console.log('Successfully unregistered controller:', thisCtrl);
            console.log('Controllers left: ' + OneOfManyManager.getCount());
        } else {
            console.warn('WARNING: The controller wasn\'t registered !', thisCtrl);
        }
    });
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/79CYb/)**.